# how to do an iterative process for a fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I have a fortran code that computes the solution vector using the thomas algorithm subroutine.

I want the solution vector to run in a loop for a certain number of time.

How do i call this subroutine in the loop?

my subroutine is the thomas algorithm subroutine.

It returns the solution vector u but I want it to use the vectors NN times in a loop. So the old u becomes the new u to use in the subroutine.

How do I do this?
Below is the what i tried

```
program thomasalg2
implicit double precision(A-H,O-Z)

real*8, dimension(9,1) :: a,b,c,r,u,uold!the dimension is subject to change depending on the size of the new matrix
!real*8, dimension(9,50) :: W
real*8 :: pi
real*8 :: h,k,lm,l,T
integer :: i,j,al,NN,n

l = 1!right endpoint on the X-axis
n = 9 !number of rols/cols of the coefficient matrix with boundaries included
T = 0.5 !maximum number of the time variable
NN = 50!number of time steps
np = n

h = l/n
k = T/NN
al = 1.0D0 !alpha
pi = dacos(-1.0D0)
lm = (al**2)*(k/(h**2)) !lambda


do i = 1,n
    r(i,1) = sin(pi*i*h) !this is W_0
end do

a(1,1) = 0.0D0
do i = 2,n
    a(i,1) = -lm
end do

do i = 1,n
    b(i,1) = 1 + (2*lm)
end do

c(9,1) = 0.0D0
do i = 1,n-1
    c(i,1) = -lm
end do


!the 3 diagonals are stored in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd & 4th files respectively.
open(10, file = 'thom1.txt')
open(11, file = 'thom2.txt')
open(12, file = 'thom3.txt')
open(13, file = 'thom4.txt')

write(10,*)
do i = 1,n
    write(10,*) a(i,1)
end do

write(11,*)
do i = 1,n
    write(11,*) b(i,1)
end do

write(12,*)
do i = 1,n
    write(12,*) c(i,1)
end do

write(13,*)
do i = 1,n
    write(13,*) r(i,1)
end do


open(14, file = 'tridag2.txt')

write(14,*)

n = 9

do i = 1,n
    write(14,*) a(i,1),b(i,1),c(i,1),r(i,1) !write the given vectors in the file in the form of a column vector
end do

call tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)

!solve the given system and return the solution vector u
do i = 1,NN
    call tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)
    !write(15,*) u
    r = u
end do

open(15, file = 'tridag2u.txt')

write(15,*)
!write the solution vector in the form of a column vector
do i = 1,n
    write(15,*) u(i,1)
end do


!print *, "Your data has been written in 'tridag2.txt'"
```

end program thomasalg2

subroutine tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)
    implicit double precision (A-H, O-Z)

```
integer n, NMAX
real*8 a(n), b(n), c(n), r(n), u(n)
parameter (NMAX = 500)

integer j
real*8 bet, gam(NMAX)
if(b(1).eq.0.) stop "tridag: rewrite equations"
bet = b(1)
u(1)=r(1)/bet
do j = 2,n
    gam(j) = c(j-1)/bet
    bet = b(j)-a(j)*gam(j)
    if (bet.eq.0.) stop "tridag failed"
    u(j) = (r(j)-a(j)*u(j-1))/bet
end do
do j = n-1,1,-1
    u(j) = u(j)-gam(j+1)*u(j+1)
end do
!print *, "The solution is", u
return
```

end subroutine

Comment: If `a`, `b`, `c` are the diagonals and `n` is the size, which between `r` and `uold` is the input (known term) and which the output (solution)? I assume `r` is the rhs and `uold` is the solution. They have the same size, so you just have to copy `uold` into `r` before the end of the loop, no?

Comment: the ouput is u and r is the input.

Comment: What of this                                                                                                              
   do i = 1,NN
        call tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)
        r = u
    end do

Comment: What is the meaning of NN? Why should the subroutine run in a loop? What is your aim?

Comment: Sorry I couldn;t post the whole code initially but now I have. I want to solve a backward difference heat equation and NN is the number of time steps

Comment: The code above is right. I had just put in the wrong values. Thanks for the help